# 2x if statements (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)

Tags: javascript, html

I cant seem to get this working, i want to check if route AM-1 is selected and then if the value "1vlucht" is also selected and change innerHTML accordingly.
Is this even possible? I also tried stuff with && but no luck.

Im not even sure if u can use 2  tags for 1 function. First time trying these features.

```js
        function priceRoute(sel)
        {
         // PRIJZEN
         if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "AM-1" ) 
            {
             
                if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "1vlucht" )
                {
                 // PRIJS PER VLUCHT
                 document.getElementById("pricePervlucht").innerHTML = "100,-";
                    document.getElementById("pricePervlucht2").value = "100,-";
                    
                    // TOTAAL PRIJS
                    document.getElementById("priceTotaal").innerHTML = "100,-";
                    document.getElementById("priceTotaal2").value = "100,-";
                    
                    // BESPARING
                    document.getElementById("priceBesparing").innerHTML = "0,-";
                    document.getElementById("priceBesparing2").value = "0,-";
                }
        
             else if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "2vluchten" )
             {
                 // PRIJS PER VLUCHT
                 document.getElementById("pricePervlucht").innerHTML = "90,-";
                    document.getElementById("pricePervlucht2").value = "90,-";
                    
                    // TOTAAL PRIJS
                    document.getElementById("priceTotaal").innerHTML = "180,-";
                    document.getElementById("priceTotaal2").value = "180,-";
                    
                    // BESPARING
                    document.getElementById("priceBesparing").innerHTML = "20,-";
                    document.getElementById("priceBesparing2").value = "20,-";
             }
            }
        }
```

```html
<select name="listingtypeRouteAM" id="listingtypeRouteAM" onchange="priceRoute(this);">
                        
        <option value="AM-1">AM-1</option>
        <option value="AM-2">AM-2</option>
        <option value="AM-3">AM-3</option>
        <option value="AM-4">AM-4</option>
        <option value="AM-5">AM-5</option>
                          
</select>

<select name="listingtypeAantalvluchten" id="listingtypeAantalvluchten" onchange="priceRoute(this);">

    <option value="1vlucht">1 vlucht</option>
    <option value="2vluchten">2 vluchten</option>
    <option value="3 vluchten">3 vluchten</option>
    <option value="4 vluchten">4 vluchten</option>
    <option value="5 vluchten">5 vluchten</option>
    <option value="6 vluchten">6 vluchten</option>
    <option value="7 vluchten">7 vluchten</option>
                  
</select>
```

Comment: How it is not working, exactly? And what are those other elements not shown in your code?

Comment: What does _change the HTML accordingly_ mean? Where is `pricePervlucht`?

Comment: your first and second "if" statement are checking the same select box for values in different select boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code in a few ways. Please ask in comments for clarifications:

```js
function priceRoute() {
    // PRIJZEN
    if (document.getElementById("listingtypeRouteAM").value == "AM-1" && document.getElementById("listingtypeAantalvluchten").value == "1vlucht" ){
        document.getElementById("innerHtml_div").innerHTML = "whatever you want here";          
    } else {
        document.getElementById("innerHtml_div").innerHTML = ""; 
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="listingtypeRouteAM" id="listingtypeRouteAM" onchange="priceRoute();">
    <option selected disabled>Please select an option</option>
    <option value="AM-1">AM-1</option>
    <option value="AM-2">AM-2</option>
    <option value="AM-3">AM-3</option>
    <option value="AM-4">AM-4</option>
    <option value="AM-5">AM-5</option>
</select>

<select name="listingtypeAantalvluchten" id="listingtypeAantalvluchten" onchange="priceRoute();">
  <option selected disabled>Please select an option</option>
  <option value="1vlucht">1 vlucht</option>
  <option value="2vluchten">2 vluchten</option>
  <option value="3 vluchten">3 vluchten</option>
  <option value="4 vluchten">4 vluchten</option>
  <option value="5 vluchten">5 vluchten</option>
  <option value="6 vluchten">6 vluchten</option>
  <option value="7 vluchten">7 vluchten</option>
</select>

<div id="innerHtml_div"></div>
```

Comment: Because jQuery is never once mentioned in the question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It can still be helpful, even if not universally helpful. The user might not have mentioned jquery because they aren't aware of it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca maybe I was a bit too hasty to use jquery (as it wasn't too difficult to remove it) -
 just changed answer to not require it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question